# What's a word for the ability to discern another's mental state?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to avoid some common implications of *empathy*: that it's mostly involuntary, and that it involves some re-experiencing of the other's feelings. I'm looking for a more general word (or, less ideally, short phrase) that could easily apply both to someone empathetic and to Hannibal Lecter.

On the other hand, I'm not looking for an overly general word like *perspicacity* or *discernment*; I'm hoping for something that's specifically about perceiving other people's emotions and motivations.

Ideally I'm hoping for a noun, but a verb ("to exercise this ability") or adjective ("possessed of the ability") would be helpful too.

Comment: I'm scratching my head about your description of empathy.  Empathy is understanding someone else's emotional state because you have experienced the same thing.  Sympathy is the ability to understand without having the experience.  I can sympathize with an astronaut who complains about motion sickness but I cannot empathize with him or her.

Comment: @michael_timofeev, you have now made me look up _empathy_ in no fewer than 7 online dictionaries, and not one of them even hints at "having experienced the same thing" being a part of the meaning of empathy. I believe in practical use it's the opposite actually: the ability to understand and vicariously experience another's feelings when one _hasn't_ experienced the same is the hallmark of a particularly empathetic person.

Comment: Folks, when downvoting a question that isn't blatantly inappropriate or unclear or stupid, please comment about why you're downvoting. That's how we learn how to ask better questions.

Comment: I remember these words clearly because two of my students wanted to do a presentation about empathy and sympathy in the workplace and wanted to present a video discussing empathy and sympathy.  I had to look up the origin of empathy and its difference with sympathy so I could understand the words because the speakers in the video did not.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: I think that *empathy/sympathy* distinction only applies to a specific subset of the meanings of both words. As OP indicates, most dictionaries wouldn't include *by virtue of having experienced similar emotions in similar contexts* as a relevant factor in the more general definition of ***empathy*** (or the *lack* of such prior experience in their definition of ***sympathy***).

Comment: This is a tough one because there is what the dictionary says, the etymology of the words, misperceptions on the Internet and finally what everyone thinks the words mean.  Hard to say who's right or wrong in this case...myself included.

Comment: @michael_timofeev, Your description sounds like some entirely legitimate but specialized usage; your recollection of having once researched the origins of these words in response to a specialized video presentation is not enough to overturn the perceptions on the internet, my experience with both words, and the seven dictionaries I've checked just today, which are all in agreement.

Comment: Sympathy usually means caring/feeling sorrow/pity. Empathy usually means feeling another's feelings. Empathy without experience is not impossible but severely limited; we do have imaginations but they have their limits, especially when it comes to imagining extremes of emotion not felt before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXMnc2Xjj-o is a show dealing with psychopaths, centered on the neurologist James Fallon, who famously studied the brain function of condemned serial killers who were diagnosed as being psychopath. Quite by accident he discovered that, if brain function is diagnostic, he was a psychopath himself.

During the discussion, the distinction is made between **cognitive empathy** and emotional empathy. Cognitive empathy is the ability to detect and recognize the emotional state of another person, while emotional empathy results in *caring* about them.

Finally, some analysts also include "compassionate empathy" http://www.danielgoleman.info/three-kinds-of-empathy-cognitive-emotional-compassionate/ In this view, emotional empathy produces a sharing of feeling, while "compassionate empathy" produces a desire to help the other.

Answer (score 8):

**perceptive**  might fit.

> **perceptive** *adjective* having or showing sensitive insight.

eg.

> 'Did you notice how quiet Bill was when Sue was talking about their holiday together? It makes me wonder if something happened that they're not telling us about.'
>
> 'Hmm! Now that you mention it, you're right. That's rather perceptive of you.'

Answer (score 6):

"**to read someone** [like a book]"

**Example**

*I don't understand John.*

*Oh, I can. I can read him like a book.*

*Yes, you are very good at reading people.*

*That's right I can read him and I can read his motives.*

> read someone like a book 
>   ...
>   2 Understand someone’s thoughts and motives easily.
>
> http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/read

Answer (score 3):

[It was as though] **he could see inside my head**.

(Pretty similar to "he could read me like a book," which is also very good.)

Answer (score 3):

In psychology, this is called [**theory of mind**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_mind):

> [T]he ability to attribute mental states . . . to oneself and others and to understand that others have beliefs, desires, intentions, and perspectives that are different from one's own.

Answer (score 2):

You use the word "perception" in your question.  I think that applies.  "I shifted uncomfortably as Hannibal looked at me perceptively.  Would he figure out my secret?"

Comment: He'd like to have you for a gourmet dinner but sense you do not have good taste

Comment: Lol...sometimes this place feels like the drinking lounge for cruciverbalists.

Answer (score 2):

Psychoanalyze.

This word appears to be like an active form of empathy without all the extra feel feel cultural implications.

Edit: also, Sherlock Holmes. Inductive or deductive reasoning may spark some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

**put oneself in another's shoes**

> "If you could put yourself in his shoes for a minute, you might
>   understand how he ended up this way."

This phrase could (conceivably) "apply both to someone empathetic and to Hannibal Lecter".

Related terms might be "**[stand in someone's shoes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stand_in_someone%27s_shoes)**" and "**[shoe-shifting](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/ambigamy/200905/empathic-intelligence-put-yourself-in-their-shoes-unlace-yours)**".

Comment: "Shoe-shifting"?  Is that a thing? I've heard the other expressions before. Are you sure that author didn't just make it up?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, I had never heard the term before reading the article today. The OP can decide whether or not it applies to his/her situation.

Answer (score 1):

MW defines ["see through"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/see%20through) as "to grasp the true nature of" which seems like a good fit.

If you [see through](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/see-through) someone or their behaviour, you realize what their intentions are, even though they are trying to hide them.

e.g.

- I could **see through** his manipulative behavior and realized we would soon be arguing.
- I can **see through** her. Actually, I can almost read her mind.