# What is the right term for a person who has the ability to put himself in other's shoes and understand their part?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I'm a person who understand things from multiple perceptive. Say you do something which seems wrong to other person. I kinda have the ability to imagine myself in your shoes and see if I would have done the same thing. I generally don't see people around me who understand things like this, they only think from their own perspective and don't usually have the ability to think from the other side. At times, this really helps me to stay neutral/unbiased.

I wanted to know about the term which can be used to refer this quality of mine. Is there any term?

Thanks.

Comment: "Put oneself in another's shoes" is literally the definition for _empathy._

Comment: the term is empathy?

Comment: Is this sentence correct? I'm an empathetic person.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/empathy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a word for the ability to discern another's mental state?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264261/whats-a-word-for-the-ability-to-discern-anothers-mental-state) ... cognitive empathy vs emotional empathy; 'put oneself in another's shoes' ....